# Setting SSM parameter as an Environment variable for EC2 - Does not work

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, ssm

I am trying to get and export an SSM parameter as an environment variable to an EC2 using the `UserData` section of Cloudformation.

The script is trying to append for e.g `export WHATS_HER_NAME=Sherlyn` to the `/etc/profile` file. But all i see in the `/etc/profile` is `export WHATS_HER_NAME=`. The value is not present. I use amazon linux 2 ami.

here is my cloudformation template.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Resources": {
    "Ec2Instance": {
      "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
        "IamInstanceProfile": {
          "Ref": "Ec2instanceProfileTest"
        },
        "UserData": {
          "Fn::Base64": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "\n",
              [
                "#!/bin/bash -xe",
                "yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap",
                {
                  "Fn::Sub": "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource Ec2Instance --configsets default --region ${AWS::Region}"
                },
                {
                  "Fn::Sub": "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}"
                },
                {
                  "Fn::Sub": "echo \"export WHATS_HER_NAME=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name WhatsHerName --region ${AWS::Region} --query 'Parameter.Value')\" >> /etc/profile"
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "GetSSMParameterPolicy": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
      "Properties": {
        "PolicyName": "GetSsmProperty",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:ap-southeast-2:012345678901:parameter/WhatsHerName",
              "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter"
              ]
            },
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Resource": "*",
              "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeParameters"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Roles": [
          {
            "Ref": "InstanceRole"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "InstanceRole": {
      "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
      "Properties": {
        "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Principal": {
                "Service": [
                  "ec2.amazonaws.com"
                ]
              },
              "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "Path": "/"
      }
    },
    "BasicParameter": {
      "Type": "AWS::SSM::Parameter",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "WhatsHerName",
        "Type": "String",
        "Value": "Sherlyn"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would try something like `"Fn::Sub": "echo \"export WHATS_HER_NAME=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name WhatsHerName --region ${AWS::Region} --query 'Parameter.Value' 2> /tmp/find-the-error)\" >> /etc/profile"` then `sudo cat /tmp/find-the-error` once the machine starts up.  `$(...)` discards stderr but this will write it to a file, instead, and perhaps give you an idea of why it isn't working.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot i tried, but the `/tmp/find-the-error` file not created

Comment: That's quite unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a fan of using JSON for CloudFormation templates so I cannot offer the solution in JSON, but here it is in YAML.

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64: !Sub
  - |
    #!/bin/bash -xe
    yum update -y aws-cfn-bootstrap
    /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource Ec2Instance --configsets default --region ${AWS::Region}
    /opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e $? --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2Instance --region ${AWS::Region}
    echo export WHATS_HER_NAME=${WhatsHerNameParameter} >> /etc/profile
  - WhatsHerNameParameter: {{resolve:ssm:WhatsHerName:1}}
```

You can read more about [using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store Secure String parameters in AWS CloudFormation templates](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store-secure-string-parameters-in-aws-cloudformation-templates/)

The snippet above is substituting *${AWS::StackName}* and *${AWS::Region}* and when it gets to *${WhatsHerNameParameter}* it checks for the SSM parameter and substitutes that into the UserData.

This mean that the UserData is complete before it gets to the EC2 instance.

Comment: but are you not getting `WhatsHerNameParameter: {{resolve:ssm:WhatsHerName:1}}` after the `export` statment?

Comment: No, because you are substituting it it is resolved before the export (similar to a DependsOn)

Comment: It should be noted here that if you were to use this for a sensitive string like a password, this approach would be inherently insecure as the value could easily show up in cleartext in logs etc.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:

1. Your instance doesn't depend on the parameter so the parameter can be created after the instance. When the instance is trying to read the empty parameter, it's just not there. Use `DependsOn: [ BasicParameter ]`.
2. You didn't include `Ec2instanceProfileTest` in your sample code. Are you sure it properly uses `GetSSMParameterPolicy`? If you run that `aws ssm get-parameter` command after the stack is done, can you get the value properly? If you can't, there might be a permission error. Check the result.

Comment: 2) yes because I can ssh into the instance and do a `get-parameter`

Comment: And yes the value is there

Comment: So probably just the order of creation. Add `DependsOn`.

Comment: Testing it now, will let you know. meanwhile is this statment ` "Fn::Sub": "echo \"export WHATS_HER_NAME=$(aws ssm get-parameter --name WhatsHerName --region ${AWS::Region} --query 'Parameter.Value')\" >> /etc/profile"` looks fine to you

Comment: nothing is written to `/etc/profile`, i am not sure why